# What are the aspects of JS binding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have the following simpliest component.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this);
    this.state = {
      name: "John"
    }
  }

  clickHandler() {
    this.setState({
      name: "Mark"
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.name}
        <button onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}></button>
      </div>
    )
  };
}

export default App;
```

If I write that

```
<button onClick={this.clickHandler}></button>
```

it says that **this** in

```
this.setState({
      name: "Mark"
    })
```

is **undefined**.
That row

```
<button onClick={console.log(this)}></button>
```

shows that **this** is **App**.
So if **this** is **App** why clickHandler does not bind automatically to that object before the dot?

```
<button onClick={this.clickHandler}></button>
```

As far as I understand in *"context.function"* the context should be bound to the function. Or it only works for *"context.function()"*?

Comment: You need to compare `onClick={this.clickHandler}` with `onClick={function(e){console.log(this)}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or it only works for "context.function()"?

That's exactly right. It depends on where the function is invoked.

Doing

```
<button onClick={this.clickHandler}></button>
```

passes the `clickHandler` as a parameter. React's internals see something not completely dissimilar to:

```
function button({ onClick }) {
  // ...
  theActualDOMButtonElement.addEventListener('click', onClick);
}
```

or

```
function button({ onClick }) {
  // ...
  theActualDOMButtonElement.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const reactCreatedSyntheticEvent = retrieveSyntheticEvent(e);
    onClick(reactCreatedSyntheticEvent);
  });
}
```

You're passing the `this.clickHandler` as a parameter, not invoking it immediately - since it gets invoked later, and *how* it's invoked later determines the `this`, you can't just do `onClick={this.clickHandler}` without making sure the `this` is correct, such as invoking the function inline, or by using a class field, or by using a functional component.

Comment: So you mean that how it's invoked later determines the this. What is the process of that invoking? And why this is later being determined to undefined?

Comment: If the function isn't bound or an arrow function, then: if it's called like `someObj.someFn()`, its `this` will be `someObj`. If it's called like `someFn` - not as part of an object - it's `this` will be `undefined` or the global object, depending on whether you're in strict mode or not.

Comment: So someObj.someFn (not someObj.someFn()) is just a parameter that CANNOT be used without binding method. That means we only take the someFn from SomeObj and the fact that someObj is before dot doesn't have any impact in this case.

Comment: Yes - if it isn't invoked in the same expression, the fact that it's part of an object makes no difference. `onClick={someObj.clickHandler}` is just like `const handler = someObj.clickHandler; ... onClick={handler}`

Comment: Last question is about arrow functions. Why () => clickHandler() binds context?

Comment: It's not that it binds, it's that it gets invoked at a place where you can control it - when you write the `()` in your own code, you can control the calling context.

Comment: <button onClick={() => this.clickHandler()}></button> The calling context is the button?

Comment: The calling context is what comes before the `.` (or `[]`). `obj.fn()` -> `obj` is the calling context. `fn()` -> no calling context.

Comment: Thank you. () => syntax plays the invocation control role. Understood.